# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I recently asked [Windows gets stuck uninstalling display languages](https://superuser.com/questions/853422/windows-gets-stuck-uninstalling-display-languages), which wasn't received well, and got 2 downvotes, and I'm wondering what I did wrong/how I can improve the question.

I can't really think of any more information I could include, I've put what the issue is, the different ways I've tried to resolve it (granted, there wasn't many ways I could think of). I've not just asked "Plz help!" (at least that's not how I read it). I was looking for help in debugging this issue so I can hopefully fix any other similar issues on my own.

Any tips on what I did wrong/could do better would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason for downvotes, I think it's pretty fine

Comment: Maybe it's just a case of me being unlucky then. Still, I highly doubt that questions perfect so I'd like to see if anybody comes up with any other tips on what I could improve.

Comment: Also, you seem to have hit the question ban. You have 2 deleted questions, both being negatively voted.. your last question also being negatively voted seems to have resulted in the post ban being applied

Comment: Yeah, that's the main reason I posted this, I wanted to see how I can improve on this SE site, as this is the only one I've been Q banned on.

Comment: There is a lot of expectation that you would have tried something, even if you would not know what to try? An expectation that you would look at the logs, and the event viewer, even if you do not know where to look? There is an expectation that you would have looked up the problem on a search engine, and attempted one of "solutions" even if that could have made things worse. I do not have a problem with it, and do not see the purpose in downvoting it.  This type of answer , the length of it and the user history surely showed up in the Review. It is probably the review itself that it was picked